# Add multiple data in columns using indexes pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Bellow are the steps on how I would like to get my data saved:

**Step 1**

| ID | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | rand |  |
| 4 | rand |  |

**Step 2**

| ID | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | rand | rand |
| 4 | rand | rand |

**Step 3**

| ID | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | rand | rand |
| 4 | rand | rand |
| 3 | rand |  |
| 6 | rand |  |

**Step 4**

| ID | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | rand | rand |
| 4 | rand | rand |
| 3 | rand | rand |
| 6 | rand | rand |

**Current code:**

```
from numpy.random import rand
import pandas as pd
IDS = [[1,4],[3,6]]
raws = ['A','B']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID']+raws)
print(df)

for ind in IDS:
    df.index = ind
    for raw in raws:
        df[ind][raw] = rand(len(ind))
```

**Issue:**
At the moment I have the following error: "ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 0 elements, new values have 2 elements"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure that there are way more pythonic solutions, but I could think of this:

```
from numpy.random import rand
import pandas as pd
IDS = [[1,4],[3,6]]
raws = ['A','B']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=raws)
print(df)

for ind in IDS:

    for i in ind:
        df = df.append(pd.Series(name = i, dtype='object'))

    for raw in raws:
        for i in ind:
            df[raw][i] = rand(len(ind))
        print(df)
```